Calculating true/population standard deviation from bootstrap standard deviation/standard error
I am using the coffee_ratings dataset to do a proof-of-concept calculation to estimate the population (i.e., coffee_ratings) standard deviation for the flavor variable using bootstrapping.
Step-1: set the seed and take a simple random sample of size 500.
set.seed(19790801)

coffee_sample <- coffee_ratings %>%
  select(variety, country_of_origin, flavor) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  slice_sample(n = 500) 

Stap-2: re-sample the coffee_sample 1000 times with replacement and calculate the mean flavor score of each re-sample
coffee_mean_flavor_bootstrap_dist <- replicate(
  n = 1000,
  expr = {
    coffee_sample %>%
    slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = TRUE) %>%
    summarize(mean_flavor = mean(flavor)) %>%
    pull(mean_flavor)
  }  
)

Step-3: calculate the standard deviation of mean_flavor: i.e., standard error
standard_error <- sd(coffee_mean_flavor_bootstrap_dist)

Step-4: calculate population standard deviation by multiplying the standard error by the square root of the sample size
population_flavor_sd <- standard_error * sqrt(500)
print(population_flavor_sd)

Output:
[1] 0.4847589

Problem: When I calculate the standard deviation of flavor in the original population, I get a different result.
coffee_ratings_flavor_sd <- sd(coffee_ratings$flavor)
print(coffee_ratings_flavor_sd)

Output:
[1] 0.3984421

However, the standard error multiplied by the square root of the sample size almost perfectly matches the standard deviation of flavor in the coffee_sample
coffee_sample_flavor_sd <- sd(coffee_sample$flavor)
print(coffee_sample_flavor_sd)

Output:
[1] 0.4826452

What am I missing here? Doesn't the standard error multiplied by the square root of the sample size give us an estimation of the population standard deviation?
Edit: PS I am doing this in R if you want to reproduce it.

Your supposition about the relationship between SE and SD generally holds only when using the arithmetic mean to estimate the population mean with a random sample without replacement.  That doesn't appear to be what you're doing -- it's certainly not what one does in a bootstrap.  Moreover, it appears you might be comparing the SD of a single sample to the SD of the population: you have no basis to suppose they are equal.

Definitely incorrect: at best you can hope that the square root of the number of bootstrap resamples times the bootstrap SE gives you the SD of the original sample.  There's no way the bootstrap, or any other method, can possibly give you more information about the population than is inherent in the sample you have!

Sorry deleted my previous reply by mistake. Quotes from the DataCamp course: "Although bootstrapping was poor at estimating the true population mean, it is great at estimating the true population standard deviation."  "Standard error times square root of sample size estimates the population standard deviation."  "This is an important property of the bootstrap distribution. When you don't know have all the values from the true population, you can use bootstrapping to get a good estimate of the population standard deviation.(https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses/sampling-in-r)

Frankly, I would choose a different resource for sound advice about bootstrapping.

@whuber Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to me. I didn't think the course content would have false information, especially about fundamental concepts like this. I'll read on bootstrapping more.
